# PayPal SSL Certificate Change: Testing Verisign G5 Certificate

Tags: ssl, paypal, openssl

I'am trying to confirm, that our server will be ready for the SSL Certificate Change.

According to Microsite migration on www.sandbox.paypal.com is complete.

Running:
`openssl s_client -CApath /etc/ssl/certs/ -connect www.sandbox.paypal.com:443`

returned 0 (ok)

Does this test definitively confirm that our server is ready?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The openssl connection `return code(0)` will be affirmative for this cert check, but there’s a slightly change you may want to make for the call.

Run with the following line and try the conn one more time, (I’ve added the –showcerts parameter so that the cert chain will be printed out and you may easily identify Verisign G5 root cert in there)

```
openssl s_client -connect api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com:443 -showcerts -CApath /etc/ssl/certs/
```